# How does the "let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) " work and return a value?

Tags: ios, swift4

Further to my last question, which thankfully I received help with, I'm trying to get this little bit of code to return a value for me so I can plug it into the text field on the storyboard. The code is working - but I can't work out how to return the value I need. myBalance, or btn_balance.

I've tried a "return value" but it's ignoring it.
This is my modified code. This prints "Hello" in the text field, but not the value. I'm a bit of a noobie at this and am afraid that I've jumped into the deep end a bit. I can return data from a function as in normal sessions, but this 'task' has me beaten.

```
class GetBalanceViewController: UIViewController {

var myBalance :String = ""
var btn_balance :String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var displayBalance: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //makeGetCall()

    //display the balance on the screen
   // print(makeGetCall(myBalance: btn_balance))
    myBalance =  (makeGetCall(myBalance: btn_balance))
    print("Hello...: \(myBalance)") // blank
    displayBalance.text = (makeGetCall(myBalance: btn_balance)) + "Hello" // displays "Hello" 


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

The function - with my modification, is this.

```
    func makeGetCall(myBalance: String) -> String  {
    // Set up the URL request
    let todoEndpoint: String = "https://api.jsecoin.com/v1.7/balance/auth/0/"
    //let todoEndpoint: String = "https://api.jsecoin.com/v1.7/ledger/auth/"
    //let todoEndpoint: String = "https://api.jsecoin.com/v1.7/balance/checkuserid/73276/auth/"
    let apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


    guard let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return "Error"
    }
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    urlRequest.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    // set up the session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
            print(error!)
            return
        }


        // make sure we got data
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        print("Got data")
        // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
        do {
            guard let todo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
                as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    return
            }
            // now we have the todo
            // let's just print it to prove we can access it
            print("The todo is: " + todo.description)

            // the todo object is a dictionary
            // so we just access the title using the "title" key
            // so check for a title and print it if we have one
            let index = todo.index(forKey: "notification")

            let btn_balance = (todo[index!].value)

            let myBalance = btn_balance
            print("myBalance I: \(myBalance)")
            print("btn_balance I: \(btn_balance)")

          /*
            for (key,value) in todo
            {
                print("\(key) : \(value)")

            }
           */
        /*
            guard let todoTitle = todo["balance"] as? String
                else {
              //  print("Could not get todo title from JSON")
                return
                }
         */
           //print("The title is: " + todoTitle)
            } catch  {
            print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
            return
        }

    }
   task.resume()
     return btn_balance
}
```

The Original is simply this.

```
makeGetCall()

func makeGetCall() {
.....
   }
   task.resume()

}
```

The program displays the data on in  the console ok

```
The todo is: ["notification": Your balance is 5646.65 JSE, "balance": 5646.65, "success": 1]
myBalance I: Your balance is 5646.65 JSE
btn_balance I: Your balance is 5646.65 JSE
```

So that's the question, how can I get that value, which I can get as you see, back to the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `dataTask` works asynchronously, you cannot simply return the value from `makeGetCall`. Instead, you'll have to update the data model or UI inside the closure.

You could make `makeGetCall` return `Void`, and add a `DispatchQueue.main.async` call inside the completion handler, to update the UI (and maybe something more, like updating the properties).

Something like:

```
func makeGetCall(myBalance: String) -> ()  {
    // ...

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in

        // ..

        do {
            // ...

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let balanceString = todo[index!].value as? String {    
                    self.btn_balance = balanceString
                    self.displayBalance.text = balanceString
                } else {
                    // Ooops
                    self.displayBalance.text = "?? unknown ??"
                }
            }
            // ...
        }

    }
   task.resume()
}
```

Btw: why do you use local variables `btn_balance` and `myBalance`? I guess you mean `selft.btn_balance` and `self.myBalance`. If so, you should also only write those values inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async` closure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. I've gone back to the original call
        super.viewDidLoad()
        makeGetCall()
and I'm getting the error. Module 'Dispatch' has no member named 'main'

Comment: Where do you need help? In `viewDidLoad`, you call `makeGetCall`. Since there is no return value, you do not set any `displayBalance.text` here. This is done inside `session.dataTask` in `Dispatch.main.async`.

Comment: Yes, I now know that, but I'm getting 
Module 'Dispatch' has no member named 'main'  
as a result of your code that I put into the body of func makeGetCall()

Comment: Arrg, my fault. It's `DispatchQueue`...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had an idea it must have been that from searching stackoverflow. However... now I get this
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.btn_balance = (todo[index!].value)
                    self.displayBalance.text = btn_balance
                }

Error: Cannot assign value of type 'Any' to type 'String' against both btn_balance and displayBalance.  sigh...

Comment: That's because todo maps to `Any`. You can safely do it with `if let`, I'll change my answer accordingly...

Comment: Excellent- Thanks Andreas. I'll now print this out and study it carefully. I appreciate your help.